# In Firebase Phone Authentication Some of the Mobiles not Receiving OTP?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Am using Firebase phone authentication, in that some of the mobiles not receiving the OTP to Verify the Mobile Number. For Integrating Firebase Phone authentication, am just followed the Firebase Document. Is there any restriction like it working on Higher API's only and Not Working on Lower API's.

**Here is my Java Code**

```
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            mVerificationInProgress = false;

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                toast("Invalid Phone Number");
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MobileNoVerification.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {

                toast("Quota exceeded.");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

        }
    };


private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {

    mAuth.signOut();

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks);

    mVerificationInProgress = true;
}
```

Am Call this **startPhoneNumberVerificatio** Method in **onStart()**

```
private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {

    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);

    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            } else {

                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    error_dialog("Invalid Code!");
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Is Any thing wrong in my Coding, Guide me to do it in better way.

Comment: please verify your number with country code.(ex :- +91xxxxx xxxxx)

Comment: @deep Okay i will check that.